# DateTime in USQL automatically convert to Unix Timestamp in parquet file

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a problem with DateTime value generated by *U-SQL*. 
I wrote some *U-SQL* to save data into the parquet file, but all the DateTime column automatically converted to *Int64* (Unix Timestamp).

I tried to investigate and I found some informations at https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/docs/Release_Notes/2018/2018_Spring/USQL_Release_Notes_2018_Spring.md#data-driven-output-partitioning-with-output-fileset-is-in-private-preview. All the *DateTime* will be convert to int64.

Why MS need to do that ? and how I can keep original DateTime value generated by U-SQL in parquet file.

I put an simple code bellow:

```
SET @@FeaturePreviews = "EnableParquetUdos:on";

 @I =
   SELECT DateTime.Parse("2015-05-10T12:15:35.1230000Z") AS c_timestamp
   FROM (VALUES(1)) AS T(x);

 OUTPUT @I 
 TO @"/data/Test_TimeStamp.parquet"
 USING Outputters.Parquet();
```

Result in parquet file is: `c_timestamp -Int64 datatype - 1431260135123000`

But I expected parquet file like: `c_timestamp - DateTime datatype -  2015-05-10T12:15:35.1230000Z`

Comment: Hi, in a U-SQL script I have this statement to define an input file for my procedure:
`DECLARE @inputpattern_csv string = "/FOLDER/" + @year.ToString() + @month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "{daynum:}_ex1.csv";`
The procedure has always worked, but now when I run it, it returns this error: 

`E_CSC_USER_INVALIDFILESETPATTERN: Invalid file set pattern 'daynum:' in 'adl://**************.azuredatalakestore.net/FOLDER/201904{daynum:}_ex1.csv'`
Is this also a consequence of the update?

Comment: @LorenzoBenassi

May be my script will help you. 
`DECLARE @path = "/sample/{FileDate:yyyy}/{FileDate:MM}/{FileDate:dd}.csv

DECLARE @startDate = new DateTime(2019,01,01);

DECLARE @endDate = new DateTime(2019,01,28); 

@N= EXTRACT ValueColumn1 string, FileDate DateTime from @path USING Extractors.Csv(); //replace by extractor you are using 

OUTPUT( SELECT * FROM @N WHERE FileDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) TO "/sample/outputfile.csv USING Outputters.Csv;
`